# как изменить вид данных на оси Х datetime

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график, анализ-данных

Нужно изменить вид данных на формат год(две последние цифры), месяц, день, час.
И немного повернуть, чтобы не накладывались друг на друга.
[Ссылка для скачивания данных](https://yadi.sk/d/kZ3yB_k-G_4NDg)
[image: Результат]

```py
def BUYorSELLinHOUR(date_start,data_end, dfBS):
    orders_Date = dfBS[(dfBS['date_Open'] >= date_start)&(dfBS['date_Open'] < data_end)]
    orders_Date.groupby([df["date_Open"].dt.floor('H'), "trade_Type"]).size().to_frame("trade_Type")["trade_Type"].unstack().plot.bar(rot=0, grid=True)
    plt.show()

df = pd.read_csv('testtraders.csv', header = 0, sep= ',')
df['date_Open'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_Open'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df['date_Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_Closed'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

date_start = '2019/10/11 00:00:00'
date_obj_s = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_start, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
date_end = '2019/10/11 23:55:55'
date_obj_e = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_end, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
BUYorSELLinHOUR(date_obj_s,date_obj_e, df )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
def BUYorSELLinHOUR(date_start,data_end, dfBS):
    orders_Date = dfBS[(dfBS['date_Open'] >= date_start)&(dfBS['date_Open'] < data_end)]
    dfBS['date_Open'] = dfBS['date_Open'].dt.strftime('%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    dfBS['date_Closed'] = dfBS['date_Closed'].dt.strftime('%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    orders_Date.groupby([dfBS["date_Open"], "trade_Type"]).size().to_frame("trade_Type")["trade_Type"].unstack().plot.bar(rot=45, grid=True)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=5)
    plt.show()

df = pd.read_csv('testtraders.csv', header = 0, sep= ',')

df['date_Open'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_Open'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df['date_Open'] = df['date_Open'].dt.floor('H')

df['date_Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_Closed'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df['date_Closed'] = df['date_Closed'].dt.floor('H')

date_start = '19/10/11 00:00:00'
date_obj_s = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_start, '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
date_end = '19/10/11 23:55:55'
date_obj_e = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_end, '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
BUYorSELLinHOUR(date_obj_s,date_obj_e, df )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]